# Why didn't the stormtroopers radio for reinforcements at the Battle of Endor?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi

During the Battle of Endor, Emperor Palpatine reveals some information to Luke about the [strength of the Imperial forces guarding the shield generator](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0000024/quotes) that is protecting the Death Star:

> Your friends, up there on the sanctuary moon, are walking into a trap, as is your Rebel fleet. It was *I* who allowed the Alliance to know the location of the shield generator. It is quite safe from your pitiful little band. **An entire legion of my best troops awaits them.** Oh, I'm afraid the deflector shield will be quite operational when your friends arrive.

We are not told the exact number of troops comprising the legion protecting the shield generator, but according to Wookieepedia [an Imperial legion consisted of 8,192 troops](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Legion). Even without Wookieepedia, the audience could reasonably infer that an Imperial legion numbered in the thousands of troops (perhaps the size of the [Roman unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_legion) from which we get the word *legion*, about 5,400).

With the unexpected help of the Ewoks the small Rebel force was told of a nearby secret entrance to the shield generator's command bunker and so avoided the main guard force. In the ensuing battle a force of about 100 stormtroopers and several AT-STs (an estimate based on the numbers seen during the Rebels' brief capture) fought the Rebels and the Ewoks.

The stormtroopers eventually lost the battle and the shield generator was destroyed, but why didn't they call for reinforcements? If there were about 10,000 troops in a legion and only about 100 fighting the Rebels and Ewoks then only about 1% of the Imperial force was engaged in battle. Even if the stormtroopers were concerned that the attack on the secret entrance was merely a diversion, why not send in more than a mere 1% of the available troops (especially when they started losing)?

Comment: I always understood the "legion" to include the fleet of ships lying in wait.

Comment: @phantom42 "Legion" (and "troops", for that matter) has always referred to ground forces. Besides, the Emperor treats the Rebel strike team on the moon separately from the Rebel Fleet, and says that an entire legion opposes the Rebel strike team.

Comment: They're Imperial Stormtroopers. Things like marksmanship practice, training, calling for help - only losers do that stuff.

Comment: Maybe they called and it just take time to get the reinforcements planet-side?

Comment: Don't know if there's a good canonical explanation. My impression was that the ~100 stormtroopers engaged with the Rebels was meant to be a significant portion of the Emperor's crack legion. It would have been too expensive to film a battle with thousands of extras in stormtrooper costumes.

Comment: The script says that the captured rebels were surrounded by "several hundreds of Stormtroopers.

Comment: @Max The Emperor implies that the entire legion is already on the forest moon. And since their only objective was to defend the shield generator why not already have them all planetside?

Comment: @Richard The script's figure of "several hundreds" would be a good addition to your already good answer. This would indicate that more than a mere 1% of the legion was sent against the Rebels, though not significantly more.

Comment: Was the "secret entrance" to the control bunker also part of the Emperor's trap, a lure to draw in the Rebels? If so, then presumably most of the legion would have assembled at the rear entrance to capture the Rebels.

Comment: @robertf - The secret entrance appears to have been just that. Good sense says that they never should have been allowed *near* the control room. Luckily there were plenty of troops on hand to conduct an impromptu ambush.

Comment: @Richard - Good point - perhaps the secret entrance should have led to a dummy control room. :) But in all honesty, the Emperor's whole scheme was actually quite brilliant now that I think about it in its entirety, with several layers of deception to lure the Rebels Alliance fleet into the trap. The Emperor would have made a good poker player. He just didn't foresee the Rebels would have drawn the "Ewok Uprising" and "Darth Vader betrayal" cards into their hand.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are a number of factors at play here that may explain the small number of troops involved in the engagement:

- Assuming your numbers are correct, ten thousand troops is a relatively small number to defend a base as large as the one seen in the film. Even placing sentries at 50 metres would use up a couple of thousand troops.
- When Luke surrenders, the Base Commander requests permission to go and hunt for Rebels in the vicinity of where he was found. This was clearly a decoy and would have drawn a sizeable number of troops away from the main base, let's say another thousand to be generous.

> **COMMANDER** : *This is a Rebel that surrendered to us. Although he denies it, I  believe there may be more of them, and I request
> permission to conduct a further search of the area.*
>
> **VADER** : *Good work, Commander. Leave us. Conduct your search and bring his companions to me.*

- The Rebels don't attack the force-field projector itself (the obvious target) but in fact, attack the generator control room. This is a high-value target and the front of the bunker building is likely heavily guarded (another 2-3000 troops?) The rear, however, is another matter. It's a "secret entrance" that the Rebels shouldn't have been able to find without the help of local insurgents.

> **LEIA:** *The main entrance to the control bunker's on the far side of that
> landing platform. This isn't gonna be easy.*
>
> **THREEPIO** : *He says there's a secret entrance on the other side of the ridge.*

- Vader knows the approximate size of the Rebel force, small enough to fit into a standard shuttle. Throwing thousands of troops at their location (once the engagement starts) would be overkill, especially given the ease with which the Rebel commandos were captured by the small number of troops guarding the back of the bunker.

> *The surrounding area, deserted before, is now crowded with two-legged
> Imperial walkers and **hundreds of Imperial troops**. The situation looks
> hopeless.*

- By the point that it's become apparent that they need extra troops, Chewie and the Ewoks have already knocked out all of the walkers, leaving just Stormtroopers who seem to lack the ability to communicate with the main base (due to the aforementioned ridge, perhaps, or maybe Paploo [activated the speeder bike's jammer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ewkfdEc1bg) when he stole it?). Han uses the videophone on the AT-ST to call up reinforcements from the bunker. We learn that plenty of Stormtroopers were waiting just behind the bunker door, oblivious to the fight taking place.

> **HAN/PILOT    (VO)**
> *It's over, Commander. The Rebels have been routed. They're fleeing into the woods. We need reinforcements to continue the pursuit.*
>
> **CONTROL ROOM COMMANDER**
> *Send three squads to help. Open the back door.*

Comment: You beat me to it. The commander in charge of the garrison obviously never spent time in prison. You ALWAYS keep your rear entrance heavily protected.

Comment: The quote where Vader orders the commander to conduct a search is an excellent point that indicates the troops would be spread out. This would make it more difficult for them to return to the secret entrance to engage the Rebels even if they received a call for reinforcements. But this still leaves the mystery of why the stormtroopers seemed to "lack the ability to communicate with the base", as you put it. We know from [TK-421](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/TK-421) that they have comlinks. Or maybe they made the call but the reinforcements just didn't arrive in time?

Comment: @Null - there was a ridge between them

Comment: @null - We also know that it's quite a frequent occurrence for the communicators to break down.

Comment: @Richard The ridge didn't prevent Han from communicating with the bunker to draw out "reinforcements". And the probability that all the stormtroopers' comlinks broke down at once so that not even one of them could call for reinforcements is quite low.

Comment: @null - the radio in the AT-ST was presumably more powerful. Note also that his call went through to the bunker Commander, not the base Commander.

Comment: @null Would YOU be the first Stormtrooper to admit you needed help defeating 5 rebels and a band of teddy bears?

Comment: @zibbobz - And telling Vader that you've cocked up is hardly a career-making idea either.

Comment: @Zibbobz Haha, I got a good laugh out of that. Still, you could claim after the fact that you thought there were more Rebels but were mistaken in the heat of battle.

Comment: @Null - You tell him, no you tell him. What, do I look like I want to get choked? You tell him., etc

Comment: Ridge, schmidge! We're talking about a galaxy-spanning civilization with FTL spacecraft! Even here on our little gravity well of a planet we've got hand-held satellite communication devices. You think that the Imperial Legion can't communicate clearly over a couple of miles? Pshaw!

Comment: @Richard: it is established in *Shadows of the Empire* that Vader's officers draw straws to determine who gives Vader bad news.

Comment: @BobJarvis, nor can they shoot straight.

Comment: @PaulDraper - a common problem in armies throughout history. Some estimates put the number of bullets fired per casualty produced in WW II in the 5000 - 10000 range. So it's not that stormtroopers are lousy shots - in the heat of battle nearly everyone is a lousy shot! :-)

Comment: Who says the storm troopers cannot shoot straight? Obi Wan comments on their accuracy in ANH, they neutralize the rebels on Leia's ship at the start of ANH, more instances throughout the original trilogy. For a decent analysis: http://www.reddit.com/r/scifi/comments/gwtio/regarding_the_accuracy_of_stormtroopers

Comment: @mwotton, mostly people who watched Star Wars...excluding those obsessed with Obi Wan's comparison of the accuracy of stormtroopers and sand people, and against all odds, work *really, really* hard to prove him right.

Comment: I'm surprised no one has suggested that the Rebels may have been jamming the Imperial comlinks, as Luke and Leia did on the speeder bike.

Comment: @BobJarvis:  If you read further about number of shots fired in WWII, the reason why has very little to do with marksmanship and a whole lot to do with not actually wanting to kill someone else.

Comment: @Null - There's nothing to indicate any jamming.

Comment: @Richard There is no mention of jamming in this scene. But after thinking about this question some more I remembered the speeder bike scene in which Luke tells Leia to jam their comlinks, which is another possible explanation for the stormtroopers' apparent inability to radio for reinforcements (your last bullet point). I'm just surprised it didn't come up.

Comment: @Null - I've had a re-read of the script, the film screenplay and the novelisation. While there's no mention of jamming, there is a scene where Paploo steals a speeder bike. He "grinned madly, and continued flipping switches. ". Since we know that the bikes have a jammer switch, it's at least possible that he accidentally activated it.

Comment: @Richard Clever suggestion! I think it's a bit of a long shot since Paploo flew away from the battle and possibly out of jamming range. Also, the stolen speeder bike was probably destroyed when Paploo abandoned it, although the clip you included does show Paploo rode it for several minutes.

Comment: @Null - Note that the clip is heavily edited to make his flight look far longer.